# $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R})$ is a Fréchet space

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Show that the space $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R})$ endowed with a system of seminorms
$$
q_n(f) = \int_{-n}^n |f| \quad f \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}), n \in \mathbb{N}
$$ is a [Fréchet space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space).

---

We already know, that the space is locally convex, we need to check if is is an [F-space][2].

We define a metric as follows
$$
\rho(f,g) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} \text{min} \{1, q_n(f-g)\} \quad f,g \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}).
$$
Then the metric $\rho$ is translation invariant. We need to show that $\rho$ is complete.

Choose a $\rho$-cauchy sequence $(f_m)$ in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R})$. We also know, that the sequence $\left(f_m \vert_{[-n,n]}\right)$ is $q_n$-cauchy for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This means that
$$
q_n(f) = \lVert f \lvert_{[-n,n]} \rVert_{L^1(-n,n)}.
$$
Since $L^1$ is a Banach space, we can find a function $g_n \in \left( L^1([-n,n]), q_n \right)$ such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$
f_m \xrightarrow{q_n} g_n,
$$
as $m \to \infty$.

Now we need to find $g \in L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R})$, such that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$
q_n(f_m - g) \xrightarrow{m \to \infty} 0.
$$

I tried to define $g$ as follows
$$
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
g_n(x) & x \in [-n,n]\\
0 & x \not\in [-n,n]\\
\end{cases}
$$
But this does not work, since $g$ depends on $n$.

How can I proceed from here? Thanks.

Comment: This works, but you need to realise that for $m \ge n$, function $g_m$ restricted to $[-n,n]$ is equal (a.e) to $g_n$, which follows by simple reasoning (the first one coming to my mind is that, if $v_n \to v$ in $L^1$, then $v_{n_k} \to v$ almost everywhere for some subsequence, hence from $(f_j |_{[-n,n]})_j$ and $(f_j |_{[-m,m]})_j$ you can extract subsequence $j_k$ such that $f_{j_k}|_{[-n,n]} \to g_n$ and $f_{j_k}|_{[-m,m]} \to g_m$ a.e, hence $g_m|_{[-n,n]} = g_n$ a.e. (Probably this can be done easier)

Comment: To be precise, what actually works is defining $g(x) = g_n(x)$ if $x \in [-n,n]$ for some $n \in \mathbb N_+$ (and the explanation above shows that it is well defined almost everywhere)

Comment: @DominikKutek
To be clear, for $k \geq n$ we can find subsequences $(f_{m_j}) \to g_n$ a. e. on $[-n,n]$ and $(f_{m_i}) \to g_k$ a. e. on $[-k,k]$. Then we can construct another subsequence, say $(f_{m_l})$ (omitting $f_m$): $(i_1, j_1, i_2, j_2, i_3, j_3, \ldots)$. Then $(f_{m_l})$ approaches both $g_n$ and $g_k$ on their respective intervals thus the restriction of $g_k$ on $[-n,n]$ is equal to $g_n$. Is this correct?

Comment: Easier approach is to firstly choose subsequence $(f_{m_i}) \to g_n$ a.e on $[-n,n]$ (and note that it is still true that $f_{m_i} \to g_k$ in $L_1$ on $[-k,k]$ since if the whole sequence converges, every subsequence must converge too). From this subsequence you can choose further subsequence $(f_{m_{i_j}})$ such that it converges a.e to $g_n,g_k$ respectivelly on intervals $[-n,n],[-k,k]$.